# How to submit URLs to StumbleUpon with Python?

Tags: python, url, post, stumbleupon

I'm looking for a method to submit some URLs to StumbleUpon using Python. I already tried with the su.pr API but StumbleUpon deprecated it. I'm looking for some alternative way.

Comment: It's linked with a python program I'm writing

Comment: Suggest to use the tools like Firebug from Firefox to go to the Net panel, and right-click the URL corresponding to the form you submit. Then, in the context menu, choose "copy as cURL". Then in Python, use "pyurl" to do the same way.